# noflo components not showing up

Tags: noflo

I am trying to get started with NoFlo on Windows. After following these instructions:

http://flowhub.io/documentation/getting-started-node/

I was able to start a noflo.js runtime.

However, when trying to create my first graph, I can only see some core components. Filesystem components are not available at all even though I did install it using

npm install noflo-filesystem --save

Any ideas?

Comment: Had the same problem. It appears that i had an error in my package.json file. missing comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem where the websocket cannot establish a connection to my local noflo runtime and thus not showing any components. Did you generate your `flowhub.json` with `--host localhost`? (as instructed in the guide)

Initialize a runtime with `--host autodetect` instead.

Comment: Thanks. That pointed me in the right direction. In addition, I also had to set the port to 1234 in the flowhub.json to get it to work.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Why must you set the port to 1234 though? Is that because of your flowhub project configurations?

Comment: Well, any number I guess. By default it is set to NULL which didn't work for me.